# Solving a SDE / Finding expectation Value

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

I am working on a physics problem, and have come across the following stochastic differential equation:

$dX(t) = \left( \frac{8}{3} X(t) - 3 X(t)^3\right)dt + dW$.

I have tried all the methods to solve this SDE (reduction, change of variables, etc...) and have even settled for evaluating the expectation $\mathbb{E}[X(t)]$, but the cubic term in the drift coefficient is proving to be very problematic!!

By the way, I am fully aware that global solutions may not exist/be unique, since the drift coefficient implies blow-up of solutions after some explosion time, I am curious strictly about local solutions.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model is well know as "double-well" potential. The closed form solution to $\mathbb{E}(X(t))$ is not known. See [Iacus, ch. 1.13.8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387758380).

Physically, you would expect that the global solution exists and is unique, since the drift term pushes the particle back to area around the origin every time $X(t)^2 > \tfrac{8}{9}$.

We can proceed with simulation, using *Mathematica*, using initial condition $X(0) = \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2}$, using Roessler's 3-stage stochastic Runge-Kutta scheme with strong order of $\frac{3}{2}$ (see ch. 6.3 of [doi:10.1137/09076636X](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/09076636X)):

[image]

The stationary distribution is symmetric with zero mean.

In fact, it is easy to find the pdf of the stationary distribution, see ch. 1.10.1 of Iacus. Using v10.2:

```
SDEStationaryDistribution[drift_, diff_, {x_, min_, max_}] := 
 Module[{s, y},
  s = Exp[-2 Integrate[drift/diff^2, {x, 0, y}, 
      Assumptions -> min < y < max]];
  ProbabilityDistribution[1/((s /. y -> x) diff^2), {x, min, max}, 
   Method -> "Normalize"]]
```

we have:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this information and the simulations. I was not aware that this SDE actually had a particular classification and name! I got up to numerical simulations, but, that is about it! Once again, thanks!